# Can anyone explain these snippets related to WebGL

Tags: glsl

I am referring to this [link](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-2d-image.html) for learning how to render a texture in webgl.

I am facing some doubts as it is not very easy for a beginner to understand.
What does these snippets mean for GLSL:

```
 vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;
 vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
 vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
```

Also, I don't want to fill the entire canvas if my image is bigger. I want to render all textures as a 512 * 384 (4:3), how to do that by modifying the vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I wrote the sample you linked too I'm curious how I can improve the explanation already on that site

The sample you linked to is from [this page](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html).

That page says right at the top

> This is a continuation from [WebGL Fundamentals](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html). If you haven't read that I'd suggest [going there first](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html)

That page says

> WebGL only cares about 2 things. Clipspace coordinates and colors. Your job as a programmer using WebGL is to provide WebGL with those 2 things. You provide 2 "shaders" to do this. A Vertex shader which provides the clipspace coordinates and a fragment shader that provides the color.
>
> Clipspace coordinates always go from -1 to +1 no matter what size your canvas is

It then shows an example using clip space coordinates.

After that it says we'd probably rather work in pixels and shows a shader with comments that details how to convert from pixels to clip space

> For 2D stuff you would probably rather work in pixels than clipspace so let's change the shader so we can supply rectangles in pixels and have it convert to clipspace for us. Here's the new vertex shader
>
> ```
> attribute vec2 a_position;
>  
> uniform vec2 u_resolution;
>  
> void main() {
>    // convert the rectangle from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
>    vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;
>  
>    // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
>    vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
>  
>    // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
>    vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
>  
>    gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace, 0, 1);
> }
> ```

In fact, the sample you linked to has those exact same comments in the code.

I'd love to hear any ideas how I can make that clearer

Comment: okay may be I am confused with the concepts. My apologies , but you are doing a great job . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code likely converts `a_position` from `0..N-1` texture resolution space to
`-1..1` range.

Comment: thats fine. What about the other question? Any idea?